# Javascript: walk a given element tree processing elements from bottom up

Tags: javascript, dom

This has stumped me. I have a `<div>` say and it contains an element tree, children, and children, of children and so forth. I would like to process all these elements from the bottom up. That is never process a given element unless all its children have been processed.

Clearly there is any number of leaves beneath `<div>` and we need to walk up from each one but never go past a node that has unprocessed children.

I'm wondering if this is a solve problem before I give it too much though. My gut feel is that in pro-forma the algorithm is in parts:

1. enumerate all the leaves (dead end elements in the tree)
2. walk up each of these branches to the first junction
3. enumerate all the junctions that have all their children processed
4. walk up their branches to the next junction
   etc. etc.

I can sense a pattern there, which is enumerating at any time the nodes that are fully processed (have no unprocessed children), walk up a each one to next node, and enumerate again until reaching top. Suggesting a recursive approach until the enumeration of unprocessed nodes has length zero.

Sounds quite doable, bit stumped on the most efficient approach to enumerating the nodes that have no unprocessed children. As I said if the problem is solved and has a standard solution using native Javascript, I'd be keen to exploit that.

Comment: Can you check if `[...document.body.querySelectorAll('*')].reverse()` will give you the needed order? It will not enumerate all the leaves first, but it should enumerate all the children before their parents.

Comment: Good idea. Wrote a little bottom up tree walker since. But am curious if this approach works too! Thanks.